# Chrome app packages resources

Tags: google-chrome-app

I have created a Chrome app which downloads a few external HTML files and saves them on the local file-system. I have a webview in my application named "testPlayer" which loads these external HTMLs from the file system and displays.

The external HTMLs have references to static files packaged in the Chrome extension. For example, an external HTML page might have a JSlink as:

```
<script src="chrome-extension://enknanemjbpjnnghnidblcbamidfdfmb/src/app/routed-components/home/test-player/public/javascripts/equationeditor/abc.js"/>
```

But the problem is that these Chrome app static resources throw CORS errors.
[image: Error screenshot of CORS errors]

The version of my manifest is 2. The documentation at below link says we have assign permissions in "web-accessible-resources". I have tried that but it is not working for some reason. Below is my manifest file:

```
{
  "name": "Demo Beta",
  "version": "0.0.18",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "minimum_chrome_version": "32",
  "icons": {
    "16": "src/assets/Favicon/Demo.png",
    "128": "src/assets/Favicon/Demo.png"
  },
  "app": {
    "background": {
      "scripts": [
        "chromeapp.js"
      ],
      "persistent": true
    }
  },
  "permissions": [
    "*://*/*",
    {
      "fileSystem": [
        "write",
        "retainEntries",
        "directory",
        "webview",
        "delete"
      ]
    },
    "system.storage",
    "storage",
    "chrome-extension://**",

    "unlimitedStorage",
    "webview",
    "http://*/*",
    "https://*/*",
    "system.network",
    "videoCapture",
    "audioCapture",
    "http://www.demo.com",
    "fullscreen",
    "notifications",
    "fileSystemProvider",
    "desktopCapture",
    "tabs",
    "<all_urls>",
    "identity"
  ],
  "file_system_provider_capabilities": {
          "configurable": true,
          "watchable": false,
          "multiple_mounts": true,
          "source": "file"
        },
  "webview": {
    "partitions": [
      {
        "name": "ereader",
        "accessible_resources": ["*.*"]
      },
      {
          "name": "interactive_player",
          "accessible_resources": ["*.*"]
      }
    ]
  },
  "file_handlers": {
    "text": {
      "types": [
        "text/*"
      ]
    },
    "image": {
      "types": [
        "image/png",
        "image/jpeg"
      ],
      "extensions": [
        "tiff"
      ]
    }
  },
  "oauth2": {
    "client_id": "xyu3.apps.googleusercontent.com",
    "scopes": [
      "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive"
    ]
  },
  "sockets": {
        "tcpServer" : {
        "listen": ["*"]
        }
    },
  "web_accessible_resources": [
    "app/*"
  ]
}
```

Comment: web_accessible_resources is only for extensions.

Comment: is there anything similar that we can do to make the packaged resources in the Chrome app accessible over an URL?

Comment: https://developer.chrome.com/apps/tags/webview#local_resources

Comment: Have already tried partitions, didn't work. Tried an alternate approach which worked -- On first time app load, read all static files from root directory and added them to filesystem. Then wrote a server to serve items from the filesystem and used the server prefixed URL in tags in the webview.